# dragging scaled image placed in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have an issue with dragging image that is scaled.
I've created main_canvas that contains background and image represented via bg_canvas resp. img_canvas. Then I've made coordinates of background (`panoramaX`, `panoramaY`) and image(`imageX`, `imageY`) to check if I clicked some of them and to be able to drag them.

Image is placed on top of background:

```
var drawToMain = function() 
{        
     // first clear the canvas
    main_ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    // draw the background image
    main_ctx.drawImage(bg_canvas, panoramaX,panoramaY, 600, 300);
    // do the transforms
    main_ctx.translate( imageX+img_canvas.width/2,
                                            imageY+img_canvas.height/2);
    main_ctx.rotate(angle);
    main_ctx.translate( -(imageX+img_canvas.width/2),
                                            -(imageY+img_canvas.height/2));
    // draw the img with the transforms applied
    main_ctx.drawImage(img_canvas, imageX, imageY);
    // reset the transforms
    main_ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
};
```

To drag items I'm testing if I clicked one of them:

```
function hitImage(x, y) {
    if (x > imageX_hit && x < imageX_hit + img_canvas.width * scaleFactor &&
        y > imageY_hit && y < imageY_hit + img_canvas.height * scaleFactor)
          return 1;

    if (x > panoramaX && x < panoramaX + bg_canvas.width * scaleFactor &&
        y > panoramaY && y < panoramaY + bg_canvas.height * scaleFactor)
        return 2;

        return 0;
}
```

Then I've made wheel event to scale content of main_canvas (background and image, both) where is my issue, I'm updating image coordinates there but it doesn't work for me, when I zoom-out image for example and try to drag it, it doesn't move and when I'm zoomig image is "travelling" in background:

```
canvas.addEventListener("wheel", myFunction);
canvas.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', myFunction);
function myFunction(evt) {
    var delta = evt.wheelDelta ? evt.wheelDelta / 40 : evt.detail ? -evt.detail : 0;
    if (delta > 0)  scaleFactor = scaleFactor + 0.05;
    else            scaleFactor = scaleFactor - 0.05;
    imageX = imageX * scaleFactor;
    imageY = imageY * scaleFactor;
    imageX_hit = imageX_hit * scaleFactor;
    imageY_hit = imageY_hit * scaleFactor;
    drawToMain();
}
```

[THERE](https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/shwqLz14/1/) is a exapmle of my problem.
Is there any solution, please?

Comment: What are you trying to scale? the entire canvas and the dragged object? Also where do you want the scaling to occur? at mouse point or at 0,0?

Comment: I'm trying to scale both images placed in main_canvas - this works fine. But coordinates of image in img_canvas ( Lena picture in this example ) are changing wrong.. Sometimes, when content is zoomed out I even cannot drag this image.

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex also I want the scaling to occur at 0,0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code (fixed Slavik's code, update 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// x, y to place image
  var imageX = 80,
    imageY = 80;

  var imageX_hit = 80,
    imageY_hit = 80;
    // x, y to place background image
  var panoramaX = 0,
    panoramaY = 0;

  var startX,
    startY,
    dragImage;
  // mouse coordinates in canvas
  var mouseX,
    mouseY;
// number represents scale of image and background
  var scaleFactor = 1,
        angle = 0;

    // main canvas
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = 600;
  canvas.height = 300;
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var canvasOffset = $(canvas).offset();
  var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
  var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;


  var main_ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var bg_canvas = canvas.cloneNode(); // canvas for image
  var img_canvas = canvas.cloneNode();// canvas for background

  var angle = 0;

  // draw on the main canvas, and only on the main canvas
  var drawToMain = function() 
{        
     // first clear the canvas
    main_ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    // draw the background image
    main_ctx.drawImage(bg_canvas, panoramaX,panoramaY, 600, 300);
    // do the transforms
    main_ctx.translate( imageX+img_canvas.width/2,
                                            imageY+img_canvas.height/2);
    main_ctx.rotate(angle);
    main_ctx.translate( -(imageX+img_canvas.width/2),
                                            -(imageY+img_canvas.height/2));
    // draw the img with the transforms applied
    main_ctx.drawImage(img_canvas, imageX, imageY);
    // reset the transforms
    main_ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  };

  // I changed the event to a simple onclick
  $(canvas).mousedown(function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
      case 1:
        // mouse position and test if image is hit
        startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
        dragImage = hitImage(startX, startY);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });

  $(canvas).mousemove(function(e) {
      // Im moving with image
      mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
      mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
      // move image by the amount of the latest drag
      var dx = (mouseX - startX)/scaleFactor;
      var dy = (mouseY - startY)/scaleFactor;
    if (dragImage == 1) {

      imageX += dx;
      imageY += dy;

      imageX_hit += dx;
      imageY_hit += dy;
      // reset the startXY for next time
      startX = mouseX;
      startY = mouseY;
      drawToMain();
    } 
  else if (dragImage == 2) {

      panoramaX += dx;
      panoramaY += dy;

      imageX += dx;
      imageY += dy;

      imageX_hit += dx;
      imageY_hit += dy;

      // reset the startXY for next time
      startX = mouseX;
      startY = mouseY;

      drawToMain();
    }
  });

  $(canvas).mouseup(function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
      case 1:
        dragImage = 0;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });

    // ZOOM-IN or ZOOM-OUT
  canvas.addEventListener("wheel", myFunction);
  canvas.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', myFunction);
    // COMPUTING scaleFactor - zoom
  function myFunction(evt) {
    var delta = evt.wheelDelta ? evt.wheelDelta / 40 : evt.detail ? -evt.detail : 0;
    if (delta > 0)  scaleFactor = scaleFactor + 0.05;
    else                        scaleFactor = scaleFactor - 0.05;
    //imageX = imageX * scaleFactor;
    //imageY = imageY * scaleFactor;
  //console.log(imageX, imageY);
    //imageX_hit = imageX_hit * scaleFactor;
    //imageY_hit = imageY_hit * scaleFactor;      
    drawToMain();
  }

  // test if I user clicked image or panorama
  function hitImage(x, y) { 
    x=x/scaleFactor;
    y=y/scaleFactor;

      if (x > imageX_hit && x < imageX_hit  + img_canvas.width &&
            y > imageY_hit && y < imageY_hit  + img_canvas.height)
            return 1;

    if (x > panoramaX && x < panoramaX + bg_canvas.width &&
        y > panoramaY && y < panoramaY + bg_canvas.height)
        return 2;

        return 0;
  }

    // loading images into canvas
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    var this_canvas = img_canvas;
    this_canvas.width = 150;
    this_canvas.height = 150;
    this_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 
                                                                                    0, this_canvas.width,
                                            this_canvas.height);
    drawToMain();
  };
  img.src = 'http://pgmagick.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_images/lena_scale.jpg';

  var bg = new Image();
  bg.onload = function() {
    var this_canvas = bg_canvas;
    this_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, panoramaX, 
                                                                                    panoramaY, 600, 300);
    drawToMain();
  };
  bg.src = 'http://www.ansteorra.org/graphics/background/bg_image.jpg';
});
```

Comment: Can I just ask how is it foxed?

Comment: Well, he was right for the first part, but you also needed to divide coords to the scaleFactor in order to keep the mouse and the elements positions synchronized.

Comment: Yes, it solved mouse movement but when I scale content, image should stay in the same position in background image and now it stays in the same position in mani_canvas.

Comment: Ok, try it now. The point is that when you scale, all the values inside the canvas scale as well, however the coordinates coming from the mouse are independent. You need to apply the scaleFactor to all coordinates from the mouse. Sorry for the sloppy job, I was in the middle of something. Hope it is OK now.

Comment: Perfect, you did an amazing peace of work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change `imageX`, `imageY` and `imageX_hit`, `imageY_hit` variables by multiplying on `scaleFactor`. You scale image by context.scale so you don't need change something in your coordinates. Just remember scale factor and use it in `hitImage` for checking coordinates.

I'll try to edit post and explain more clearly, if this would be solution for your problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/j1f306w5/1/

My changes:

```
function hitImage(x, y) { 
      if (x > imageX_hit * scaleFactor && x < imageX_hit * scaleFactor + img_canvas.width * scaleFactor &&
                y > imageY_hit * scaleFactor && y < imageY_hit * scaleFactor + img_canvas.height * scaleFactor)
        return 1;

      if (x > panoramaX * scaleFactor && x < panoramaX * scaleFactor + bg_canvas.width * scaleFactor &&
            y > panoramaY * scaleFactor && y < panoramaY * scaleFactor + bg_canvas.height * scaleFactor)
        return 2;

    return 0;
 }
```

and

```
  function myFunction(evt) {
    var delta = evt.wheelDelta ? evt.wheelDelta / 40 : evt.detail ? -evt.detail : 0;
    if (delta > 0)  scaleFactor = scaleFactor + 0.05;
    else                        scaleFactor = scaleFactor - 0.05;
    //imageX = imageX * scaleFactor;
    //imageY = imageY * scaleFactor;
    //imageX_hit = imageX_hit * scaleFactor;
    //imageY_hit = imageY_hit * scaleFactor;      
    drawToMain();
  }
```

Comment: Also you might want to multiply your mouse movement by `scaleFactor` to keep the correct mouse cursor to image relation.

Comment: Great solved, can I just ask you how to modify this mouse move and keep the image in the same position in background image?

Comment: I don't understand what mean. Lena's image position doesn't change related to background image position when scaling. Or you're asking about @Aides comment?